# Function not found in onformat but... it exists

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

As you can see in this image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6xqoAmB-uxZRTRuQmgzZDBvWXM

I get an error for a not found function in an onformat parameter, but the function is there!

Any hint on what else could I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Your error message talk about a function named `"_n_fences"` (including double-quotes). Double quotes are not delimiters for TBS. Check that parameter `onformat` is something like `onformat=_n_fences` or `onformat='_n_fences'`.

Comment: The little things you do not know gonna defeat you... thank you.